# What formula will I use for conditional formatting? Nothing has worked

Tags: excel, conditional-statements, conditional-formatting

I have a list of names in row 1 (Sheet2.B1:O1) and a list of 2017 dates in column A(Sheet2.A2:A390).  If the cell at the intersection is greater than 2 conditional format to highlight cell on separate sheet (Sheet1.A1).

```
                A                  B               C             D

row1                           Person A         Person B      Person C
row2         1.1.17                1               8             8     
row3         1.2.17                1               1             8       
row4         1.3.17                1               8             1
```

Comment: Thank you that update.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need more information to address this exactly, and I can't comment yet so heading here to answer for you generally speaking. We need to know what's in Sheet1. Is it only cell A1 in Sheet1 that needs to be formatted? Is it ANY cell in Sheet2 that can trigger cell A1 in Sheet1 to format?

I'm assuming it's more likely that you have a Person A, Person B, Person C, etc column in Sheet 1 that match with Sheet2. If so:

While on Sheet1, In the Conditional Formatting toolbox, creating a new rule, select "Use a formula to determine which cells to format". Then in the formula box type =Sheet2!B2>2. Select the formatting changes you want if that formula returns TRUE.

For example, if you want Sheet1.B2 to turn black if Sheet2.B2 > 2, the formula would be =Sheet2!B2>2, it would apply to Sheet1!B2, and the formatting would fill to black.

If it is indeed a 1:1 match you're interested in, then if you start in the right place, you can just apply it to all the cells that are necessary. By that I mean if you use the formula Sheet2!B2>2, you can say it applies to Sheet1!$B$2:$D$50, or whatever, and the formula reference will shift with each cell from B2:D50 (i.e. if Sheet2!C18>2, then Sheet1!C18 will turn black).

Comment: The list of names on Sheet2 row 1 is also listed down Sheet1 in Column A.      I have used the formula "=Sheet2!$B2>2" and filled that to all names listed in Sheet1 column A, but the relative reference does not change "$B2" as I fill down column A on Sheet1.  So I was questioning using an intersection formula.  I have been stuck on this so any help is much appreciated.  I hope I have explained the problem clearly.

Comment: can you post some screenshots of the two sheets?